# Publish android application to play market under Google's policy

Tags: android

I haven't published android application to Google play market and I'm planning to publish one, but in my application, I used some code fragment I suspect they can be rejected by Google.
First is open mobile data (3G/4G LTE) automatically by java reflection:

```
    public static void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    try {
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Second is open wifi automatically:

```
WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", key);
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
//remember id
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

Can anyone explain to me the possibility for both these code be rejected by Google?

Comment: Check this out http://developer.android.com/legal.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this policy if your app satisfy this
[Google Play Apps Policy Center](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4430948?hl=en)

Also refer this
[Policy and best practice](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?rd=1#topic=2364761)

If your app doesn't violate this policies than you app is safe on play store.